# Playing video in a Customview like iPad feature

Tags: iphone

When we call MPMoviePlayerController.play method, the movie player is opened and the video is played in a separate full screen. is it possible to play a video in a custom view, that is I have an image added on a view, when this image is clicked, the image has to be removed and the video has to play there itself as the feature in iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-full screen playback of video is possible in iPhone OS 3.2 for iPad.

> If you are porting an application that uses the MPMoviePlayerController class of the Media Player framework, you must change your code if you want it to run in iPhone OS 3.2. The old version of this class supports only full-screen playback using a simplified interface. The new version supports both full- and partial-screen playback and offers you more control over various aspects of the playback.

On the full-screen question, see [this section of the iPad Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH9-SW10) for further information, and [this property of MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerController/setFullscreen:animated:) specifically.

Bear in mind that you can still only play one video at a time, and that this is only currently possible for iPad.

Comment: thanks for clarifying the doubt. Partial screen play back is possible in 4.0 also.

Answer (score 0):

Not using `MPMoviePlayerController`, no.

You might be able to achieve this using a custom movie player, but I haven't seen one in the wild yet, and I don't know how it would be done.